# How to use Haskell tool xml-to-json in terminal?

Tags: json, xml, haskell

I am going to use xml-to-json to process a large xml file. I searched several methods, but they did not work due to out of memory. Then I found a tool implemented in Haskell, but when I tried this tool according to the guide, it says command not found. Could anyone please tell me how to use this tool? Thanks in advance. here is the link of the tool: https://github.com/sinelaw/xml-to-json#readme

**Update**

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaCkY.png)

Comment: The README.md has detailed instructions on how to install and use the tool. Which step are you having trouble with?

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions to install all packages needed, but when I use command: xml-to-json, the terminal says: unknown command. Because I never use Haskell before, I do not know whether the way I use the command is right. I upload the screenshot and hope that can help understand my question. Thanks

Comment: It's just a command line program like `ls`. Try `xml-to-json some-input-file.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, your executable is built but isn't in your PATH.

On many systems cabal installs things to `$HOME/.local/bin`. So you can try adding that to your PATH environment variable.

It looks like you're using a Mac, in which case the path to use is `$HOME/Library/Haskell/bin/`. [This page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Mac_OS_X#GHC) seems to have relevant instructions on how to configure Mac OS X.